# Owner-drawn CTabCtrl in WTL

Tags: winapi, wtl

WTL/WIN32 newbie here, struggling to understand how messages are passed around.

I'm trying to write an owner-drawn CTabCtrl in WTL. For some (at least to me) incomprehensible reason, WM_DRAWITEM is sent to the *parent* window, not to the window that actually needs to know. Which makes it difficult to make a nice, self-contained GUI class to simply replace CTabCtrl. I could always capture the message in the parent and pass it on to the tab control, but that would be poor OO design. Is there a way to intercept the message, *without* requiring extra re-routing code in the owner/parent class?

EDIT: After a bit of googling, I now have

```
class CQueryTabCtrl : 
    public CWindowImpl<CQueryTabCtrl, CTabCtrl>, 
    public COwnerDraw<CQueryTabCtrl>
{
public:
    DECLARE_WND_SUPERCLASS(NULL, CTabCtrl::GetWndClassName())
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CQueryTabCtrl)
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(COwnerDraw<CQueryTabCtrl>)
        DEFAULT_REFLECTION_HANDLER()
    END_MSG_MAP()

    BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
    {
        pMsg;
        return FALSE;
    }

    void DeleteItem(LPDELETEITEMSTRUCT /*lpDeleteItemStruct*/)
    {
    }

    void DrawItem ( LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis )
    {
        CDCHandle dc = lpdis->hDC;
        CDC dcMem;

        dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC ( dc );
        dc.SaveDC();
        dcMem.SaveDC();

        dc.FillSolidRect ( &lpdis->rcItem, RGB(255,0,0) );

        dcMem.RestoreDC(-1);
        dc.RestoreDC(-1);
    }
};
```

Which is obviously utterly wrong, since DrawItem() is never called.

Answer (score 1):

`WM_DRAWITEM` is sent to parent [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Sent to the parent window of an owner-drawn button, combo box, list box, or menu when a visual aspect of the button, combo box, list box, or menu has changed.

You handle it on hosting window, and with WTL you might leverage `COwnerDraw` class on it and/or reflect messages there so that they are sent back to the window where your subclassing `WindowProc` would handle them as you perhaps originally planned.

Comment: You made it wrong way. The message is sent to parent anyway in first place. You cannot work it out on just the control class.

Comment: Oh well. Ugly OO design it is, then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does WTL support message reflection in the way that MFC does?

Comment: @user1793036: I suppose you have to be more specific. Yes WTL has reflection support.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late to the party, but might help others...

There's no way to directly achieve reflected messages w/o extra routing code, because that's how Window's window messaging works, as Roman points out.

ATL however has mechanisms to reflect messages onto child windows, which at least helps in keeping self-written code to a minimum.

### 1) Opt-In to reflection

This requires an extra step in your parent window, in order to tell it to reflect messages from child windows onto them, using the `REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS()` macro:

```
// Just a made-up dialog class for outlining message reflection installed on the parent window
class SomeDialog : public CDialogImpl<SomeDialog, CWindow>
{
public:
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(SomeDialog)
        REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS()
    END_MSG_MAP()
};
```

### 2) Handle reflected (owner-draw) messages

Because your control will receive **reflected** messages, and the COwnerDraw mixin provides an alternative message map for those, you simply chain to that message map, using the `CHAIN_MSG_MAP_ALT()` macro.

```
class CQueryTabCtrl : 
    public CWindowImpl<CQueryTabCtrl, CTabCtrl>, 
    public COwnerDraw<CQueryTabCtrl>
{
public:
    DECLARE_WND_SUPERCLASS(NULL, CTabCtrl::GetWndClassName())

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CQueryTabCtrl)
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP_ALT(COwnerDraw<CQueryTabCtrl>, 1)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Also see a complete [owner-drawn tablist control](https://gitlab.com/FireDaemon/open-source/wtlext/blob/master/include/wtlext/tablist.h) from the wtlext repository, which can serve as an example (Dislaimer: I am associated with the author FireDaemon Technologies Ltd).